# Why in angularjs .append is acting as .html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to append new row to a table, where existing rows are created by ng-repeat. But, when i click on add new button rater than appending a new row, it is removing the existing rows and adding new. can any one please help me in this regard ?

here is the code and [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5owkkfu0/1/).

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("simpleController", function($scope)
 {
    var descriptions = ['item1','item2','tem3'];
     $scope.items = descriptions;

 });

app.directive("addRow",function($compile)
{
    var newRow;
    newRow = '<tr><td>New Description</td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" add-row>+</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" delete-row>-</a></td></tr>';
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element,attrs,controller){
            element.on("click", function() {
                console.log("clicked on activity add row");
                $compile(element.parent().parent().parent().append(newRow))(scope);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/5owkkfu0/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whenever we want to insert new element inside angular element, it will not understand by angular directly.
First we need to run that element through compile using `$compile` API, then append it to element.

You need to code like below. You need to first $compile you element then append it to element.

```
element.on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked on activity add row");
    element.parent().parent().parent().append($compile(newRow)(scope));
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5owkkfu0/2/)

As per @huanfeng observation, `<tr>` is not working properly, Its get converted to span. After goggling I found, there is [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) with AngularJS. For solving this you can use any of the working solution from issue link.

**Update 1**

Instead of appending element you can do this by more [**Simpler way**](http://jsfiddle.net/5owkkfu0/8/)

Only push variable inside your `ng-repeat` array i.e. `$scope.items.push('New Description')`. ng-repeat will render one more for you with your specified description.

Thanks.

Comment: Can i ask why the tr td change to span?

Comment: @huanfeng do you have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: It seems angular has some issues for using table as parent, I suggest to don't use table, use div instead

Comment: Ya it seems like issue..I have updated my answer for more better way..in @BeginnertoUI mentioned case

Comment: just we need to add `track by $index` inside `ng-repeat`, btw Appreciated your good observation :)

Comment: yes, we need the $index for delete. I found a similar plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/hVZmbI4YRy3JPBeU0m36?p=preview

Comment: downvoter, should i know the reason behind down vote?